The 9V tongue test, but with a capacitor. How different would it be?
Most of us have tried "tasting" electricity by placing a 9v battery on their tongue.
I was wondering how different would that feel if in place of a 9V battery one would use a capacitor, charged up to the same 9V, and with the legs spread apart to the same distance as a 9V battery terminal.
My (not so educated) guess would be that the current would flow much faster due to a lower internal resistance of the capacitor compared to the one of the battery, and how much current would depend on the capacitor... capacity.
But how would that feel in practice? For which capacity could this be a safe experiment?

The resistance of your tongue likely swamps out the internal resistance of the battery and capacitor, so I wouldn't expect much difference except due to the contact area of the leads vs the battery terminals.

The battery would keep the tingle going longer.

How much current depends on both the resistance and the voltage.  Since both are presumably the same, the sensation would be the same, but the duration would be as @periblepsis stated.

Of course, as @periblepsis points out the capacitor value makes a difference in the strength and duration of the sensation.  A 10 pF capacitor wouldn't have the same effect as a 1 F supercap, which would be closer to the battery.

Point contacts from the capacitor vs broader terminal area offered by the battery will be a significant factor. Is this somehow a design question?

I suppose the question might have (rather limited) practical application if you were stuck in some situation where you needed to confirm a fairly high capacitance capacitor was functional and you had no measuring instruments but you did have a 9V battery.

A 9V battery can put about 3A into a short-circuit. That is much less than than flows in your* tongue.
The circuit resistance the dominated by the biological parts so the internal resistance of the battery has little effect on tongue feel.

But how would that feel in practice?

About the same but shorter duration.
Also possibly different flavour tin vs nickel.

For which capacity could this be a safe experiment?

Any, but using something bigger than 1F seems pointless. 100uF is probably a good starting point.
(*) I test 9V batteries on my upper lip, which is less sensitive than my tongue.

The resistance of your tongue would be similar in either case, battery or capacitor. Any difference in that resistance would be due to the skin contact area of the capacitor leads being different from the contact area of the battery terminals, and the distance between the contact points being different. Calling that resistance \$R\$, by Ohms law, the current flowing would be:
$$ I = \frac{V}{R} $$
Voltage \$V\$ in each case is (at least initially) the same, so the only things changing are resistance \$R\$, and the consequent current \$I\$, which will determine the intensity of the sensation. Resistance will depend on skin contact area, and distance between the two contacts. If you lay the capacitor leads flat upon the tongue, and at a similar distance from each other as the battery contacts, so that contact area and distance is similar to the battery terminals against the tongue, I doubt you will feel much difference. If you poke the sharp leads of the capacitor into the tongue, you risk applying potential difference directly to a nerve ending, which will definitely hurt, and maybe even damage the nerve.
The sensation would be stronger, and become more painful, the closer the terminals become to each other, because resistance through the tongue falls with distance, and current rises commensurately according to Ohm's law. To a large extent, this has nothing to do with the the capacitor's ability to source more current, because both are equally able to source hundreds of milliamps. There will be some distance at which battery current cannot rise any further, but capacitor current can still rise. However, I think that by the time you reach this point (if it's even possible), it's certainly already very painful, and maybe already causing nerve and skin damage.
Also, be aware that if you allow a capacitor's leads to touch each other directly, while still holding a charge, and while in contact with the tongue, the resulting spark and heating will cause burning of the skin.
Assuming similar skin contact area and distance, the only noticeable difference would come from the fact that the battery will maintain 9V potential difference between its terminals forever (until it exhausted), while the capacitor's voltage will reduce steadily from 9V to 0V over time. Depending on the capacitance, this could be microseconds or minutes. Capacitance will determine the duration of the experience, not the intensity. At a guess, from a 100μF capacitor you can expect the experience to last a couple of seconds, initially battery-like in intensity, but dimishing quickly. I haven't tried this, so that's just an educated guess.
